# The code is not able to take the input for name?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

No changes to the class can be done so I cant add any new functions which sets the name for me.

```
class ele
{

char* name;
public:

ele() :name(nullptr){}
~ele()
{
    if (name)
        delete[]name;
}
char*& GetName(); 
};

#endif
```

I try to access the name but it gives me error after cin Debug assertion failed. Invalid null pointer.

```
>   `     char*& ele::GetName()
    {
    cout << "Please Enter the name"<< endl;
        cin >> this->name;
        return  this->name;
      }`
```

Comment: `this->name` is `nullptr` since that's how you initialized it in your constructor. You cannot read from `std::cin` to `nullptr`. You need to allocate storage at some point and set `name` to point to it. You can save yourself a lot of trouble by using `std::string`.

Comment: I am curious to find out what is `char*&` type?

Comment: Tell the person who wrote this horrible class that the `nullptr` check in the destructor is redundant.

Comment: @RawN this is a reference to char*, you can do this for example: `ele.GetName() = nullptr` to set ele::name to nullptr. I am not saying it makes sense, `GetName` should be a const method, returning `const char*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot change your class (and use `std::string`) you need to at least allocate memory before `cin>>this->name`, now you are using a null poitner which is UB. So your fix would look as follows:

```
if (this->name == nullptr)
   this->name = new char[64]; // << !!
cin >> this->name;
```